# Pourquoi a-t-on un « De » après l'adjectif « Drôle » ?

Tags: adjectifs

J'ai vu qu'il fallait ajouter la préposition « de » après l'adjectif « drôle ».

Je me demande donc s'il  existe d'autres adjectifs devant être utilisés avec « de » ?
S'il y en a, pourriez-vous me donner leur liste ?

Answer (score 6):

Il me semble que tu as rencontré un cas d'utilisation particulier du mot drôle.

Lorsqu'on souhaite employer le sens "comique, amusant, rigolo" de l'adjectif drôle, il est utilisé comme le sont ces autres adjectifs :

> Il m'a montré une vidéo amusante.
>
> Il m'a montré une vidéo drôle.

Toutefois, drôle a un autre sens bien différent. Il signifie également "bizarre, inhabituel".

> C'est étrange qu'il ne te l'ait pas demandé.
>
> C'est drôle qu'il ne te l'ait pas demandé.
>
> Cette femme est bizarre, tu ne trouves pas ?
>
> Cette femme est drôle, tu ne trouves pas ?

Cette formulation est assez peu rencontrée. En français, on préfère recourir à la locution adjectivale "drôle de". Elle signifie elle aussi "bizarre, étrange" et lorsqu'elle est utilisée, elle se place avant le nom qu'on souhaite qualifier.

> J'ai vu un drôle de mendiant dans le train !
>
> J'ai vu un mendiant bizarre dans le train !

Je ne peux citer de mémoire un autre adjectif qui peut être utilisé avec la préposition "de".

Comment: Il y en a bien quelques uns, mais très peu qui ne soient pas vulgaires.

Answer (score 3):

C'est une tournure idiomatique, assez rare il me semble.

On la trouve aussi pour l'adjectif « idiot(e) », (attesté dans le TLFi):

> (TLFi) cet idiot de La Faloise! dit Georges tout à coup (ZOLA, Nana, 1880, p. 1382). Et regarde, regarde, la grande idiote de fille, j'en étais sûre,

Bien que non attestés dans le dictionnaire on entend parfois cette construction avec les adjectif « fou », « folle », et « imbécile » et d'autres moins courants comme « déginguandé », « dévergondée » etc.

Comment: *Pauvre de lui !*

Comment: *Ce grand timide de Jacques*